# Autowired object is null while creating model

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Im struggeling with quiet an easy issue.
While creating model for my service by Autowired, object is all time null. Here is how I define my Components.
Controller

```
@RequestMapping("")
@RestController
@Log
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private JiraService jiraService;
...
```

Service:

```
@Component
@Getter
@Setter
@Log
public class JiraService {
    @Autowired
    JiraClientModel jiraClientModel;

    public JiraService(@Value(value = "${jira.credentials.userName}") String userName,
                       @Value(value = "${jira.credentials.password}") String password,
                       @Value(value = "${jira.url}") String url,
                       @Value(value = "${jira.jql.query}") String query) throws URISyntaxException {
        jiraClientModel.setSomeValues // here I want to assign some of my values but Model is null

    }
```

And my Model:

```
@Component
@Getter
@Setter
public class JiraClientModel {
    private SearchRestClient searchRestClient;
    private String query;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your application producing an instance of `JiraClientModel` somewhere (in a method annotated with `@Bean`)?

Further, do you really need an injected instance, you can just create your own:

```
@Component
@Getter
@Setter
@Log
public class JiraService {

    private final JiraClientModel jiraClientModel = new JiraClientModel();

    public JiraService(@Value(value = "${jira.credentials.userName}") String userName,
                       @Value(value = "${jira.credentials.password}") String password,
                       @Value(value = "${jira.url}") String url,
                       @Value(value = "${jira.jql.query}") String query) throws URISyntaxException {
        // ...
    }
```

Also, `@Autowired` injections are not recommended any more, constructor injections is the way to go for modern Spring.

I personally don't see much use in having normal objects being produced by Spring instead of just being created the "normal" Java way - I mostly use dependency injection when working with services or components.

Comment: Well that works, but what if I want to add Autowired objects to Model? Then Component cant be initilized with "new".

Comment: In your `@Configuration` class you could have a method `public JiraClientModel jiraClientModel` that is annotated with `@Bean` that has to return this object then. But as I wrote before, I would not put `@Autowired` into normal Java classes anyway.